# Project Build classes do not include external project imports

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have a project which imports another projects to its build path. When I clean the project to compile classes, the classes imported from external projects are not showing up as part of the compiled classes directory.

Do anyone know how to make sure these external import classes gets compile and included into my build classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. But when you deploy your project, you'll certainly want to create a jar file to hold all your classes. And Eclipse has a wizard to export a jar file and choose to embed dependencies in the jar.

The usual way, however, is to have each project generate its own jar, and to use all the jar of the project + the jars of the dependencies as the classpath of the deployed project.

Comment: I dont want to generate a jar file - I want the classes to appear on my compiled classes directory.

Comment: If the two projects should have the same output directory, then they should be merged into a single project. This is how Eclipse projects work. Now you can use ant and copy all your classes where you want to.

Answer (score 1):

@Bitmap,
is this a WAR or EAR project?
In EAR project you have to specify clearly the "JAVA EE Module dependency" to include the referenced projects.

If you include a project as a build dependency, it will be for compile-time only.

If these are simple java projects you may want to look at "JAR JAR" [enter link description here](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/)

to achieve this.

HTH

Comment: It is a standard java app. But I can convert it to EE if this will sort the issue. As posted on JB Nizet answer, all i want is to make sure the external classes imported show up at compiled classes directory.

Comment: Yes, convert it to an EE project, mark the dependent projects as java EE module dependency. Just to be clear what this will do is when you create a EE project, it will automatically add the dependent project as a jar module. Is this what you want? It will not show in the compiled directory, but the dependent project will be added as a .jar file.  If this does not work try creating a new source folder inside the main project and reference (linked source in Eclipse) the source folder of the dependent project. See if that works.